# lunarvim LSP issues in git projects

Tags: lunarvim

I have been using lunarvim for the last few months working on a NON-git C++ project with great success.

The tree structure is very simple:

**C:\project\source**

so I used to

```
cd c:\project\source
```

and then

```
lvim <file>
```

and everything (LSP and everything else) works flawlessly.

Now we have the same project, but moved to git, so that c:\project has a .git folder.

When I **cd** into the usual source folder and invoke **lvim** on a file, I can't find anymore references to a functions (**gr**), or see symbol info (**K**), while other things like go to definition (**gd/gD**) seems to work.. sometimes..

my **:pwd** shows **c:\project** instead of **c:\project\source**, and even if I manually **cd** into **c:\project\source**, it get reset to **c:\project** at the first (unsuccessful) **gr**.

What is happening? and how can I resolve these issues?

**Note:** if I **cd** into the old (non-git) folder, everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to recreate the compile_commands.json file in the new project folder.. my bad.